# Can you tell me,what would be the Xpath -(I want to click on the 'img' with 'div' id="abc")?

Tags: xpath, testcomplete

```
 **<div id="abc"> 
<img class="xyz",src="def">
</img> Firm </div>**


 <div id="lmn"> 
<img class="xyz",src="def">
</img> PO </div>
```

Here 'img' object is actually a collapsed or expanded button and the same properties of this 'img' have been used at other places as well, so I cant take its 'class' or 'src' directly.I am using "vbscript" in testcomplete. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

xpath for selecting `<img>` having parent `<div id="abc">` :

```
//div[@id='abc']/img
```